# WFFM error :Empty strings are not allowed.Parameter name: errorMessage

Tags: wffm

I am facing a weird issue with WFFM.

I have used WFFM module for contact us page in website.
In the form i have few required fields which i marked as required using WFFM.
Most of the time form validation works.But after few hours same page gives exception. This issue comes in some regular intervals( like 1-2 day)

The immediate fix which i am doing is the reset IIS or recycle app pool.
sometimes reset IIS not works in that case i have to do a reset IIS+ web.config modification(any kind of modification).

Is there any permanent Fix for this?

I am using Sitecore 8.1(update 1) + supported WFFM
also, Language fallback is enabled.

I am sensing this issue is related to Cache.

Below is the exception details.

[image]

Please let me know if anyone has solution for this.

Thanks

Comment: did you add any custom validation to fields & missing error message for them ? Your Error log shows something like that.

Comment: Hi  @BalajiKuppuswamy No i am not using any custom validation.

Comment: Are you using 'FileUpload' FieldType of WFFM ? if yes please read this for implementation. http://ggullentops.blogspot.in/2016/05/sitecore-wffm-mvc-fileuploadfield.html . Also worth looking into below link since your exception logs show 'DynamicValidationBase' related issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38278133/sitecore-8-0-build-3-mvc-wffm-custom-validator-not-working   please revert if it resolves your issue.

Comment: As language fallback is enabled, I assume you have a multilingual solution. Please read this http://ggullentops.blogspot.be/2016/02/translating-wffm-mvc-server-error.html to set multilingual error messages. Not sure if it will fix your error, but worth a try (as you will read, error messages are cached indeed and maybe you get an empty value when someone fills the form first in a language that has no error message set). Can elaborate in an answer if applicable.

Comment: Hi @Gatogordo , I went to the location "/sitecore/system/Modules/Web Forms for Marketers/Settings/Meta data/Mvc Validation Error Messages" and enabled fall back for all kind of error messages.. its been 6 days in Row.. didn't got the error . Hope that is resolved the issue.. will keep you posted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As language fallback is enabled, I assume you have a multilingual solution. Please read [this](http://ggullentops.blogspot.be/2016/02/translating-wffm-mvc-server-error.html) to set multilingual error messages. As you will read, error messages are cached indeed and maybe you get an empty value when someone fills the form first in a language that has no error message set.

Setting the language fallback on the error message fields (located in `/sitecore/system/Modules/Web Forms for Marketers/Settings/Meta data/Mvc Validation Error Messages`) should fix it as well as that would lead to a version of your error messages is all languages.